# How to release complex object manually

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
class SimpleObject{
    NormalObject obj1;
    NestedCustomObject obj2;
    List<Obj extends Timer> threadObj1;
    List<Obj extends Thread> threadObj2;
}
```

Such Thread obj is running on.

How to release an obj manually like that (SimpleObject obj)?

Will System.gc() release it automaticly if obj=null?

**More Detail**

`After assign null value to the object and call System.gc(), program suspend on the thread again whill debuging`

> it seems that thread obj will not be release automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to destroy java objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404964/how-to-destroy-java-objects)

Comment: Thread is still running after obj=null and System.gc(). It is not duplicate problem.

Answer (score 0):

`System.gc()` is a hint to `JVM` , `JVM` may chose to ignore it. There are no way to force garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks but your answer seems have nothing to do with my problem.